# A question on the colours of the hydrogen spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen

Why does hydrogen have 4 lines in the atomic spectroscopy and not more?

I mean when an electron get excited it has more than 4 possible ways to return to the ground state. So why we see only 4 lines?

Comment: That's not true. Why would you think that?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series
I guess you are referring to the visible spectrum, e.g the Balmer series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series
But there are many more lines in the ultraviolet and infrared.

Answer (score 2):

The electron can emit radiations in different frequency ranges. They are the  Lyman, Ballmer, Paschen, Brackett, Pfund, Humphrey series and other series for n>6. They correspond to the de-excitation of electrons to n= 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 respectively. Lyman series is in the ultraviolet range, Balmer series in the visible range and Paschen, Brackett and Pfund series in the infrared region.